# Text concatenation for localization purposes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to localize my app using this method: [How to implement localization in Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578341/how-to-implement-localization-in-swift-ui)

In general it works. One problem I found is with text concatenation. Example: I have a translation for the text "bookings". To make it work I need to separate my previous code:

```
Text("bookings: 40")
```

to be:

```
Text("bookings")
    .fontWeight(.bold)
+ Text(": 40")
    .fontWeight(.bold)
```

Translation still works. The problem is that right now I need to have text formatting twice (in this example: fontWeight, but sometimes it's more complex).

I have tried to make it more simple like this:

```
Text("bookings" + ": 40)
    .fontWeight(.bold)
```

This code works in English, but is not being translated now to another languages. How should I change my code to make it work and keep it simple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Text` localization works with string interpolation, see for example the [WWDC 2019: What's new in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/402/) session video, or [Localization in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/10/16/localization-in-swiftui/), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593008/1187415).

However, you have to use the correct format specifier. For strings, it is `%@`, for integers it is `%lld`. Example:

```
let value = 40

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("bookings: \(value)")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
}
```

with  the localization entry

```
"bookings: %lld" = "Buchungen: %lld";
```

in the Localizable.strings file results in the text "Buchungen: 40" to be displayed in a bold font:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) It works. However, I have changed the code slightly. `let stringValue = ": \(value)"` and then I just translate `"bookings%@" = "Buchungen%@";`.
This way I am keeping this order of label: value

Comment: @mallow: You are welcome. – But actually my statement *“you have to convert the integer to a string first”* was wrong, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Anyone except me experiencing no success with any of the "%lld" or "%@" techniques I have seen here or elsewhere? XCode 11.4 b3.

Comment: @HelloTimo: I worked for me when I wrote the answer – the screenshot is not a fake :)

Comment: @MartinR No doubt. Maybe a current beta bug.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone else facing the issue that using %@ or %d don't localize concat-ed strings? I'm facing this issue iOS 13.3 XCode 11.3.1