# Prevent Text("string") from being exported as localization

Tags: swiftui, localization

I have a few `Text("dummy")` within SwiftUI previews. Every time I perform export localizations, these would get exported. Is there any way to manually mark them as "do not localize"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Text("") and Text(verbatim: "") initializers in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505679/difference-between-text-and-textverbatim-initializers-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use with verbatim constructor, like

```
Text(verbatim: "dummy")
```

Answer (score -1):

Convenient way to use keep always safe and get rid of Text() localisation globally. It will override the default init and get rid of localisation.

```
extension Text {
    public init<S>(_ content: S) where S : StringProtocol {
        self.init(verbatim: String(content))
    }
}
```