# SwiftUI how to stop text change with email address in Text()

Tags: swiftui

I have a grid that is displaying different fields, and the email field, i want to display as white text, however even specifying white, it changes the color to a link the moment I set it to an email address.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                        Text("Email")
                            .font(.custom("heavy", size: 18))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("Test1234@gmail.com")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.custom("regular", size: 14))
                    }
```

[image]

How do I stop it from changing the foreground color or remove the fact its trying to define a link all together?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Text(verbatim:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(verbatim:)) to tell it to not format the text.

Code:

```
Text(verbatim: "Test1234@gmail.com")
```

[Difference between `Text("")` and `Text(verbatim: "")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505679/difference-between-text-and-textverbatim-initializers-in-swiftui)

Comment: Thank you! Never heard of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                        Text("Email")
                            .font(.custom("heavy", size: 18))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text(verbatim: "Test1234@gmail.com")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.custom("regular", size: 14))
                    }
```